# SQL to update field of jira table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, jira

```sql
UPDATE cg
SET NEWSTRING = ''
FROM changegroup cg
inner join jiraissue i on cg.issueid = i.id
inner join project p on i.project = p.id
inner join changeitem ci on ci.groupid = cg.id AND ci.FIELD='Access Matrix Table'
inner join app_user au on cg.author = au.user_key
WHERE cg.issueid=(select id from jiraissue where issuenum = 124 and project in (select id from project where pname = 'NTW Customer Incident Management'))
```

I have error cg relation does not exist. Can Somebody help
where it is syntactically incorrect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) the alias of the target table needs to be provided in the UPDATE part, not the FROM part.

```
UPDATE changegroup cg
  SET NEWSTRING = ''
FROM jiraissue i, 
     project p, 
     changeitem ci, 
     app_user au 
WHERE cg.issueid = i.id 
  AND i.project = p.id
  AND ci.groupid = cg.id AND ci.FIELD='Access Matrix Table'
  AND cg.author = au.user_key
  AND cg.issueid = (select id 
                    from jiraissue 
                    where issuenum = 124 
                      and project in (select id 
                                      from project 
                                      where pname = 'NTW Customer Incident Management'))
```

The target table can't be used in a JOIN condition, so it's easier to move all join conditions to the WHERE clause.

Comment: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "cg"
LINE 5:   inner join changeitem ci on ci.groupid = cg.id AND ci.FIEL...
HINT:  There is an entry for table "cg", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: @jirajira: ah I didn't see the other references. You need to move all join conditions to the WHERE clause then.

Comment: It looks fine but still getting ERROR:  column "newstring" of relation "changegroup" does not exist

Comment: @jirajira: well, as you didn't show us the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the table in question, I can't help you with that. **You** should know which columns your table has and what the correct spelling for them is.

Comment: newstring is column from **changeitem** therefore I was trying to join them
I was following [atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/retrieve-issue-change-history-from-database-in-jira-server-933695139.html) for select and need update

Comment: But you are trying to update the column `newstring` in the table **`changegroup`**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Why did you get rid of the `join`s?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: As you can't `JOIN` to the target table, I thought it was less confusing using a common "join style" rather than mixing implicit and explicit joins

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Yucch.  I disagree but respect your viewpoint.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I am the last one to consider using the dreaded implicit joins, but mixing implicit and explicit joins is not a good idea